# How can I erase part of a mesh using another mesh?

Tags: mesh

I need a way to erase accurately a part of a mesh, using another mesh.

[image: Two intersecting meshes]

I need the big mesh to have a gap where the smaller mesh is.
I don't need the smaller mesh, so it doesn't matter if it gets destroyed in the process/

Comment: use a boolean Mod

Comment: I realised that might help, but I have no idea how to do so, when I tried, nothing happened

Comment: answered.....read below

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished with a boolean modifier.

Add it on the large mesh and set the type to difference, then set the smaller mesh as it's target.

[image]

once you apply the modifier, you will have a hole in the large mesh, you may delete the small mesh

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it but it didn't work, turns out I had a copy of the mesh visible, so I didn't see the gap

Comment: if this solves your problem, accept it so we can mark this as solved.